# Using Tree Sitter, How to disable extras in string literal?

Tags: regex, grammar, lr-grammar, treesitter

I am writing a Tree-Sitter grammar, I want to include escape sequences as child nodes within string literals, but I also want to avoid matching comments as extras within string literals.

The input `"https://example.com"` is not parsed correctly because of the `//`.

```js
extras: $ => [$.comment],
rules: [
    comment: $ => choice(
      seq('//', /[^\n]*\n?/),
      seq('/*', /([^\*]|\*[^\/])*/, '*/'),
    ),
    escape: $ => /\\./,

    // This one detects escape sequences, but fails on `//`
    string: $ => seq('"', repeat(choice(/[^\"\\]/, $.escape)), '"'),

    // This one doesn't detect escape sequences, but does not fail on `//`
    string: $ => /"([^\"\\]|\\.)*"/,
],
```

I tried the `token.immediate` modifier, but I did not manage to make it work (I don't really understand how is it supposed to be used). In the following example, the calls to `token.immediate` have no effect.

```js
string: $ => seq('"', optional($._string_tail), token.immediate('"')),
_string_tail: $ => seq(
    choice(
        token.immediate(/[^\"\\]/),
        alias(token.immediate(/\\./), $.escape)
    ),
    optional($._string_tail)
),
```

I also tried to put a lower precedence on comment rule, but it has no effect.